# Can I donate dark spells while my dark spell factory is upgrading?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I tend to be one of the highest donators in my clan, and one of the few people who regularly donate dark spells. Because of the update, there is now a new dark spell available at my level, so I started upgrading it, and I am without dark spells for quite sometime. Is there a way to donate them still, or do I have to rely on someone else to fill the donations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can still donate dark spells while your dark spell factory is upgrading. To do so, tap on the donate button, then tap on the donate now button, and you will be able to select which dark spell you wish to donate, however it will cost you 10 gems to do so. This is quite handy if you don't mind spending the gems, as dark spells can be very important in attacks, and you can make sure people will still be able to get them if no one else is on to donate.

Note: This only works for spells you have unlocked. The new spell you are upgrading to unlock will not be available to donate until your spell factory is done upgrading. This is also possible to do for any troop if you happen to be upgrading all barracks of that type, or just want to instantly donate the troop/spell to someone.

Comment: Does this mean you can donate spells without building them beforehand?

Comment: @Ellesedil if you mean donate them before brewing them, yes. The donate now button allows you to donate any dark spell or any troop you have unlocked instantly, regardless if you have your barracks or dark spell factory are upgrading or not or if your army camp/spell factories are full.

Comment: @Ellesedil no you cannot. But I can at least still donate poison, earthquake, and haste spells if my clan members need them for war, so that is good enough for me.